# Making local html file contents in the same domain

Tags: html, subdomain

I've html contents with following folder structure:

```
             "Parent folder"/"child folder..."
        (showing only the minimum required contents)
```

Each child folder has a index.html file. I load them in the browser using file path url example: "file://parent folder/child folder/index.html".

I want to make each one of the child folder is in same domain. So, that they can share resources which I'll provide when the first page loads. One example of the resource would be locale. All other page loads, will use the same resource.

Help appreciated in guiding me, achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I completely understand your question, as you do not use domans when accessing files directly with file://... However, if you are asking how to make relative links to files in different directories you can do it like below:

To make a reference outside of the current directory (i.e. parent directory) use ..

So, if you want to insert an image from file://parent_folder/child1/index.html to file://parent_folder/child2/image2.jpg you could do so like this:

```
<img src="../child2/image2.jpg" />
```